# Изменение наследника при отрицательном z-index

Tags: css

Как при наведении на item показать button с отрицательным z-index, чтобы кнопка была кликабельна?

```
<div class='item'>
    <div class='button'></div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/gx6ow7xL](https://jsfiddle.net/gx6ow7xL/)

Comment: Проблема в том, что при наведении на .button он исчезает?

Comment: @Invision, да, hover теряется. Ничего в голову не приходит как сделать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы сделал примерно так

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 256px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 16px 8px 16px 16px;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
.item-wrap {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
.button {
  width: 25px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #5D5D5D;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -40px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  transition: margin-left .3s ease;
}
.item-wrap:hover .button {
  margin-left: -25px;
  transition: margin-left .3s ease;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  margin: 4px 0 0 -20px;
  background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class='item-wrap'>
  <div class='item'>content 1</div>
  <div class='button'><span class='icon'></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Как вариант использовать wrapper уже рассматривал, да вот до кнопки всё равно не дотянуться, она выдвигается отлично, но не кликабельна :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gx6ow7xL/2/ немного поколдовал и вышло, спасибо. При абсолютном позиционировании во враппере инедкс ведёт себя хорошо. Только кнопку пришлось переместить после итема

Comment: @Doofy Ass, ваш вариант на хроме как минимум и без индексом отработал, к слову).